# CLLoacationManager class returning cached data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

How to remove cached data which is sent by CLLocationManager and how to increase its accuracy.Every time i launch the app it gives me cached data and updates it after some time.I have seen several threads but i am not able to get a concrete sol .can anybody provide me the code?
I am using the following method to get position data....

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

I have set the delegate and accuracy here.....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
bestEffortAtLocation = nil;
latLocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
longLocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
locationManager =[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter =  kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}

Also can i use CLLocationManager to compute the distance travelled by person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to dump the cached data. The docs recommend using the timestamp property of the `CLLocation` object to determine how recent the data is, which is what I do.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    //wait until we get a recent location, no more than 2 minutes old
    if([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow] <= (60 * 2)){
        DLog(@"New location:\n\tLat: %f\n\tLon: %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        //turn off location updates
        [self.locManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        DLog(@"Stopping Location Updates");
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

In my testing I haven't had to wait more than a second or two before I get new data.

On your second point, you could have a variable that you add to whenever you get a location update. The distance between updates can be pretty easy to get using `CLLocation`'s [`distanceFromLocation:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:) method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of set the distanceFilter to kCLDistanceFilterNone

i.e.  locationManager.distanceFilter =  kCLDistanceFilterNone;

You may give some value to distanceFilter and check

For e.g.  locationManager.distanceFilter =0.5f;

And to calculate distance travel you have to implement the didUpdateToLocation: fromLocation:

where you have to find the new latitude and longitude

Finally 
CLLocationObject = newLocation;

CLLocationDistance yourdistance = [newLocation getDistanceFrom:CLLocationObject];

NSString *distance = [[NSString alloc]
        initWithFormat:@"%gm", yourdistance ];

NSLog(@"you have travel=%@",distance);

Comment: i have used the value of distanceFilter = 1.0 still it is updating the location when iPhone is still.

Comment: Do you test it in iPhone device over wifi or through any carrier

Comment: hi razz............actually  i have tested the application in iPad (device).....!